# how to get inner content of xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

how to get inner content of xml in android?
For example if the

I have used following code but it does not return actual result..

```
String xml ="&#60;hello>&#60;hai>welcome&#60;hai>&#60;/hello>";

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));           
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(is);                  
String response = document.getElementsByTagName("hello");
```

I need the result "<hai>welcome<hai>"..Thanks in advance

Comment: An example: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i did this:
i made 2 functions, getxml() checks if there are child nodes
and xmltagswtf() returns the rest of code

```
public String getxml(Node b){
    String va = "";
    if (b.hasChildNodes()==true){
        int nodes = 0;
        int a=b.getChildNodes().getLength();
        while (nodes <a){
            Node c = b.getChildNodes().item(nodes);
            if(c.getNodeName()!="#text"){
            va+="<"+c.getNodeName()+">"+getxml(c)+"</"+c.getNodeName()+">";
            }else{
                va+=getxml(c);
            }nodes+=1;
        }
    }else{va=b.getTextContent();}
    return va;

}
public String xmltagswtf(String xmlt, String what) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlt.getBytes("UTF-8"));           
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();  
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(is);                  
    NodeList response = document.getElementsByTagName(what);  
    Node nod = response.item(0);
    String nodos = "";
    if (nod.hasChildNodes()==true){

        int nodes = 0;
        int a=nod.getChildNodes().getLength();
        while (nodes <a){
            Node c = nod.getChildNodes().item(nodes);
            nodos+="<"+c.getNodeName()+">"+getxml(c)+"</"+c.getNodeName()+">";
            nodes+=1;
        }
    }else{
        nodos+=nod.getTextContent();
        System.out.println(nodos);
    }
    return nodos;
}
```

then do something like this:

```
String xml ="<hello><hai>welcome</hai></hello>";
String hai =xmltagswtf(xml, "hello");
```